# Error inesperado al crear una aplicación en Android

Tags: java, php, android

Llevo ya un tiempo investigando cómo solucionar este error pero no encuentro respuesta por ningún sitio.

> Value `<br` of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to *JSONObject*.

En español sería:

> El valor `<br` de tipo `java.lang.String` no puede ser convertido a *JSONObject*.

El caso es que desde la aplicación de *Android* que estoy desarrollando cuando hago una consulta *HTTP* y me devuelve un *JSON* sale ese error y no sé por qué.

Código *Java*:

```
package com.secondworld.grabthesky;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvregister;
    EditText etnombre,etemail,etpass;
    String TAG = "registro";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        tvregister = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rRegistro);

        etnombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rUser);
        etemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rEmail);
        etpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rPass);

        tvregister.setOnClickListener(l1);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener l1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    RegisterActivity.this,
                    "Registrando...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            registrarUsuario();
        }
    };

    public void registrarUsuario() {

        // Obtener valores actuales de los controles
        final String nombre = etnombre.getText().toString();
        final String email = etemail.getText().toString();
        final String pass = etpass.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

        map.put("nombre", nombre);
        map.put("email", email);
        map.put("pass", pass);

        // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

        // Depurando objeto Json...
        Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());

        // Actualizar datos en el servidor
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(
                new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        Constantes.REGISTRARSE,
                        jobject,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                // Procesar la respuesta del servidor
                                procesarRespuesta(response);
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                ) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    /**
     * Procesa la respuesta obtenida desde el sevidor
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            // Obtener estado
            String estado = response.getString("estado");
            // Obtener mensaje
            String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1":
                    // Mostrar mensaje
                    Toast.makeText(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            mensaje,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Enviar código de éxito
                    RegisterActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    // Terminar actividad
                    RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                    break;

                case "2":
                    // Mostrar mensaje
                    Toast.makeText(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            mensaje,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Enviar código de falla
                    RegisterActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                    // Terminar actividad
                    RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Código *PHP*:

```
require 'User.php';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Decodificando formato Json
    $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    //Clave codificacion
    $clave = "l1Oia0JMKZFrDcPBAl0Znw";

    // Insertar usuario
    $retorno = Usuarios::insertUsuario(
        $body['nombre'],
        $body['email'],
        // $body['pass']
        md5($clave.$body['pass']
        );

    if ($retorno) {
        // Código de éxito
        print json_encode(
            array('estado' => '1','mensaje' => 'Creación exitosa')
        );
    } else {
        // Código de error
        print json_encode(
            array('estado' => '2','mensaje' => 'Creación fallida')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se presenta tu objeto json en el log?: `Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());`

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el servidor está devolviendo como respuesta un `JSONObject`? Algunos servidores devuelven un `JSONArray` en vez de un `JSONObject` y si es un Array el tratamiento es diverso. Me ocurría eso en una app y el problema era que el servidor devolvía el JSON así: `[{.....}]` en ese caso es una JSONArray.

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());` muestra el json que se envia al servidor `{"email":"emailprueba","nombre":"usuarioprueba","pass":"contraseñaprueba"}`

Comment: Y lo que devuelve el servidor aquí : procesarRespuesta(response); puedes verlo de alguna manera ? Quizá no esté devolviendo un JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error me ocurría en una app que estaba realizando.

**En mi caso el problema era que el servidor no estaba devolviendo un JSONObject, sino un JSONArray.**

La diferencia entre ambos es simplemente que el JSONArray viene entre [], mientras que el JSONObject viene entre {}.

Ejemplo de JSONArray:

```
[{"estado":"Ok","mensaje":"Registro realizado. Gracias."}]
```

Ejemplo de JSONObject:

```
{"estado":"Ok","mensaje":"Registro realizado. Gracias."}
```

La lectura cambia según lo que estés recibiendo.

**A. Si recibes un JSONArray**

1. Debes cambiar el tipo en el Response.Listener

   `new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {`
2. También en el onResponse

   `public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {`
3. También en el método al que le pasas la respuesta. En el cual deberás cambiar también la forma de leer el JSON:

   ```
   private void procesarRespuesta(JSONArray arrJson) {

       try {
              //Del JSONArray recibido se extrae el JSONObject, todo lo demás queda como ya lo tienes
              JSONObject response = arrJson.getJSONObject(0);

              // Obtener estado
              String estado = response.getString("estado");
              // Obtener mensaje
              String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
   ```

**B. Si recibes realmente un JSONObject**

El problema está en otro sitio, quizá un JSON mal formado. Trataría de ver, quizá a través de la URL el resultado que arroja el servidor y lo validaría usando cualquier herramienta en línea como [JSONLit](http://jsonlint.com). O por algún motivo el servidor no está devolviendo nada, u otra cosa que no es un JSON. En este caso **es importante ver lo que devuelve el servidor**.

**C. El servidor no está devolviendo nada**

Es importante siempre verificar que el servidor esté devolviendo e incluso programar nuestra app para que nos informe cuando el resultado no es el esperado, sea porque no hay conexión en el servidor o porque no se encontraron datos o por otro motivo.

Comment: he conseguido aisoar el problema, por lo menos es lo que creo, en el arcgivo php he creado un formulario que envia los datos mediante post y loq eu recivo en `file_get_contents("php://input")` es esto `"nombre=asdasd&email=asdasd&email=asdasd&submit=Registrarse" ` al usar la funcion `json_encode();` devuelve un **NULL** por que creo que no puede parsera esa cadena en ese formato.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por toda la ayuda recibida, pero después de invertir miles de horas en el código he descubierto que ese error da cuando en el archivo php hay un error de programación y salta el error, de esta manera devuelve el mensaje de error que esta codificado en HTML donde se encuentra el 
.